# Jmeters test standard

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am using JMeter to test my own web application with the HTTP request. The final result seems okay. But I have one question are there any details of testing standard? Because I am writing a report which needs some data as a reference.

For example, something like the connected time and loading speed should lower than XXXXms or sample time should between XX and XX

I didn't find there are any references about this. So is there anyone knows about this which I can be used as reference data

Comment: Most of the cases the business need and the user experience defines the requirements. This is done by excessive tests with random people. It is a good rule of thumb to have every response a subsecond one. This way it feels smooth, but there is no universal guideline I am avare of. For further knowledge on the topic chat with UX developers.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will be able to find "references". Normally when people invest into performance testing they have either [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) to check or they better spend money on performance testing to see if/when/where their system breaks instead of loosing it for every minute of system unexpected downtime.

So if you're developing an internal application for your company users will "have to" wait until it does its job as they don't have any alternative. On the other hand they will loose their valuable time so you will be like ["serial programmer John"](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/51qbzj/bad_code_kills/)

If you're running a e-commerce website and it is not responsive enough - users just go to your competitors and never return.

If you still want some reference numbers:

1. According to a report by Akamai, [49% of respondents expected web pages to load in under 2 seconds](https://www.scribd.com/document/300122029/Akamai-Performance-Matters-Key-Consumer-Insights-eBook#scribd), while 30% expect a 1-second response and 18% expected a site to load immediately. 50% of frustrated users will visit another website to accomplish their activity, while finally, 22% will leave and won't return to a website where problems have occurred
2. Similarly, a [Dynatrace survey last year](http://snip.ly/FI5D#http://www.dynatrace.com/content/dam/en/general/holiday-shopping-report.pdf) found that 75 percent of all smartphone and tablet users said they would abandon a retailer's mobile site or app if it was buggy, slow or prone to crashes.

See [Why Performance Testing Matters - Looking Back at Past Black Friday Failures](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-performance-testing-matters-looking-back-past-black-friday-failures) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Feng,

There is no standard acceptance criteria for application performance. Most of the time Product owner takes the decision of acceptable response time, but we as a performance tester should always recommend to keep the response time within 2 seconds.

If you are running the performance testing first time of your application then its good to set the benchmark & baseline of your application based on that you can run your future tests and suggest the recommendation to the development team.

In performance testing, you can set benchmarks for following KPIs

- Response time
- Throughput

Also, its recommended to share detailed performance report to the stackholders so that they can easily take their decision. JMeter now provides [Dashboard Report](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/09/generating-jmeter-report-dashboard/) that has all the critical KPIs and performance related information.